# Storage projects with eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, project, storage

Regularly develop projects in PHP using Dreamweaver but I would start using Eclipse.
I have my machine in a directory where they are armaezandos projects, but also a place where projects are published in apache.
In Dreamweaver in the project settings I map the local directory, setting to perform the sending of files to the apache automatically after you save them.

I wonder what the correct way to develop with Eclipse.
If I map the project directly in the apache directory (thus having only one copy of the project) or if the Eclipse has some configuration to achieve the same functionality I have in Dreamweaver.
Another problem is that when mapping the project directly in Eclipse are created folders and files .settings, .buildpath and .project.

Note: Keep copies of two projects (one local and one in apache) for the purpose of tests not send files, uploads, etc. in memoento that you publish the project, and sending only the project folder location.

I use Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Apatana based off of Eclipse, pretty much the same way when storing projects. However I map my virtual hosts files to my project folders. I also keep revision control through Subversion so if any hiccups occur they can immediately be fixed. Just map your Apache Virtual Hosts files to your project folders.

Comment: And when you publish these files anywhere else, sends all configuration files as much as the Eclipse SVN?

Comment: No, you just simply ignore those files... its not that hard. That is due to carelessness, not because of use.